# Comparing two columns in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two columns and I want to compare the values in each row and create a third column that will tell me true or false (or 0/1) like the below example.

```
Col1    Col2   Col3
24      24     true
45      45     true
56      54     false
78      98     false
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please have a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) guide. SO isn't a code service community.

Comment: Have u tried using 'case' expression , and have u tried anything yet.

Comment: i've tried                   select 'TotalBookedFare', 'MyNewFare',
 CASE WHEN 'TotalBookedFare' = 'MyNewFare' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as MyDesiredResult

Comment: And thats two strings you compare ? That will equal to zero. Otherwise if it is columns its the right way.

Comment: yes, comparing two columns. i must just be putting this in the wrong place in the script. thanks for confirming that is the correct syntax though

Comment: @Bennett, if you are comparing columns, don't enclose the column names in quotes. The CASE expression in your comment should work then, although returning 0/1 instead of true/false.

Answer (score 1):

Personally a [`CASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) expression is probably the easiest and simplest way to do this.

```
SELECT col1, 
       col2, 
       CASE 
         WHEN col1 = col2 THEN 'True' 
         ELSE 'False' 
       END AS Is_A_Match
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a case expression.

```
 case when col1 = col2 then 'true' else 'false'
```

or in bit form

```
case when col1 = col2 then 1 else 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
select col1, col2, case when col1 = col2 then 'true' else 'false' end as col3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a column into the table, then you can use a computed column:

```
alter table t add col3 as (case when col2 = col3 then 1 else 0 end)
```

If the columns can have `NULL` values and you want to treat those as equal, then the logic should take this into account.

This column is then available when referring to the table.

If you just want the result in a query, use a `case` expression as described in several other answers.